# WAMP giving 403 error when loading content from different page

Tags: jquery, wampserver

I'm developing a narrowcasting site in ExpressionEngine 2.10.1 that loads content from differrent pages using jquery. The site is hosted localy using WAMP server with c:/Projects/ as document root. The error that I recieve is:

```
POST http://narrowcastingwbg.local/default/news/algemeen 403 (Forbidden)    jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
```

I tried changing settings in the apache httpd.conf file and I changed the file permission but that did not work. Any ideas to what the problem could be?

Comment: Yes. It would be better to leave WAMPServer set with the default DocumentRoot as it originally was and then create an Apache Virtual Host for each of your projects. [See this post for help doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) Alternatively WAMPServer 3.0.0 has a menu Item that will build you a Virtual Hosts from a question and answer page automatically

Comment: Thanks for your reaction @RiggsFolly. The site has been put online at this url: http://narrowcasting-wbg.portalserver.nl/algemeen. As you can see in the console the errors are still there. I hope that the site will be able to give you some specific information about the problem I'm having.